# rendererAdd function for Spark DataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, itemrenderer

Like we have rendererAdd function/hook for a Spark List which is dispatched when an itemrenderer is added to the container ?

Do we have any similar method/hook at DataGrid level also ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you more concerned with just catching when an item is added to the dataProvider or when it is actually put into the list on screen?

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#itemAdded()

Comment: Thanks for replying but Spark DataGrid does not extends ListBase and so I cannot use this.

Comment: The way I got to this link was to click the "itemAdded" method description in the Spark List documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#methodSummary (it's in the protected methods--make sure you have Show inherited methods on)

Comment: That's not the concern, the problem is that the DataGrid component is not a list, it's an entirely different component, so that function is not available.

Comment: You can watch for them to hit the stage, and then address them.

Comment: As a workaround, i dispatched a custom event from the "set data()" function in my custom renderer and caught that event in the host component to pass any data to the event.target which is the item renderer. And it worked :-)